# React Native render Base64

Tags: react-native, caching

I am using react-native-image-cache (https://github.com/georstat/react-native-image-cache) to reduce image download requests and I have created a custom hook for it:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { CacheManager } from "@georstat/react-native-image-cache";

export const usePrefetchBlob = (url: string | undefined) => {
    const [blob, setBlob] = useState<undefined|string>()

    const prefetch = () => {
        if (url) {
            CacheManager.prefetchBlob(url).then(response => setBlob(response));
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        prefetch()
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        prefetch()
    }, [url])
    
    return {
        blob
    } as const
};
```

Then in my component I do:

```
const { blob } = usePrefetchBlob(organisation.logo_image_url)
```

And I render with the Avatar component (https://wix.github.io/react-native-ui-lib/docs/components/media/Avatar):

```
<Avatar
     source={{ uri: `data:image;base64,${blob}` }}
/>
```

When it works it works really good. But sometimes the image is not loaded into the component like in the following screenshot:

[image]

But when I click on it (there is no action linked to pressing on the Avatar) it appears:

[image]

I have tested that the images are being downloaded and cached.

So how can I fix this? Or what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried it without using the Avatar component? Also, you shouldn't need the first useEffect in your hook.

Comment: You can use the fast image(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fast-image)

Comment: @Abe I want to use the Avatar component. With normal Image it works really good.

Comment: @NensiKasundra I want to use Avatar component

Comment: @Dirk You can make Avatar with this one

Comment: Sounds like the issue is with the Avatar component then.

Comment: @NensiKasundra how do you mean? WIih FastImage its not possible to pass a child component right?